# Выборка значений из таблицы в форму/ select

Tags: mysql, html, php, sql

```
<select name="city">
  <option value="">Select...</option>
  <option value="1">spb</option>

  <option value="2">kiev</option>
  <input type='submit' name='formSubmit' />
</select>
```

как отредактировать чтобы **названия городов** из таблицы mysql выводились в форму?

Comment: Вы вообще знаете, что такое ХТМЛ? Хотя бы элементарнейшие основы?

Comment: если работа с бд то select заключается в форму
я не прав?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Вариант 1.

1. Делаете выборку из базы данных средствами PHP.
2. По очереди в цикле перебираете каждую строку выборки
3. Средствами PHP выводите в браузер **option** с нужными параметрами.

Вариант 2.

1. Выводите на страницу пустой **select**
2. Средствами JavaScript, а в частности ajax делаете запрос к серверу.
3. Сервер возвращает названия городов в каком-нибудь формате, например json.
4. Динамически создаете элементы списка уже на стороне клиента средствами JavaScript.

Comment: Что это за портянка у вас такая интересная!)